# Supermarket Simulation in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, queue

I have a task which looks like this [TASK1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94LNs.png)

I wrote few lines which i can get maximum customers market got , arrival time and serve time for each customer but I can't understand how should i track time and queue to get answers to question a) and b).
My code is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct customer {
    int serveTime;
    int arriveTime;
} customer[1000];

int main()
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int randArrive, randServe, longestWait, currentQ, totalTime=0, i;

    randArrive = rand() % 4 + 1;
    customer[0].arriveTime = randArrive;
    customer[0].serveTime = rand() % 4 + 1;
    totalTime += randArrive;
    currentQ = 1;

    for ( i=1; totalTime<720; i++ )
    {
        customer[i].arriveTime = rand() % 4 + 1;
        customer[i].serveTime = rand() % 4 + 1;

        if ( customer[i].arriveTime < customer[i-1].serveTime )
            totalTime += customer[i-1].serveTime;
        else
            totalTime += customer[i].arriveTime;
    }

    printf( "%d,%d", totalTime, i );

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: New to coding as a student every tip would help thanks.

Comment: Please explain what the difference between the variables `i` and `totalTime` is supposed to be? Why not only have one variable which specifies the current time of the simulation in minutes (which can be between 1 and 720)? You may want to add comments to your code to specify the exact meaning of every variable.

Comment: If `totalTime` is supposed to keep track of the total time a single customer spent in the store, then you must keep track of that information for every single customer, not just one variable for all customers. In that case, `totalTime` should be part of the `struct customer`.

Comment: i is for customer number like i'th customer to get rand numbers and totaltime is for total time passed after adding times passed for each customer. Yes i saw that forgot to initialize totalTime its 0 at the beginning of course.

Comment: I have now successfully written my own solution to your task. However, I will only post it if you ask me to, because I don't want to spoil your success of writing the solution yourself.

Comment: Why should every customer have its own `serveTime` data member? In my solution, it was sufficient to only have one single variable `serveTime` for the whole program, because there is only one customer being served at once.

Comment: According to the algorithm specified in the task, you are supposed to do one loop iteration per minute of the day. However, you are doing one loop iteration per customer instead. I don't think you will be able to solve the problem this way.

Comment: I see what you mean there. I thought i can do it for every customer with adding times eachother but like you said looping for time looks like makes more sense. Thanks for the thought of spoiling but it's timed task and i have deadline tomorrow. I would be happy to see your solution.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel uhm.. If you still there can i see your solution? Deadline is close and i have to finish it. I am sure your solution will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for my solution to the task.

Please note that I did not stricly follow the algorithm described in the task. According to the task, the customer currently being serviced is not supposed to be part of the queue, but should be dequeued before being serviced. However, I found it easier to program if you consider the customer currently being serviced as the customer at the start of the queue.

The task also requires that you change the maximal arrival time from 4 to 3 and observe the changes. Since I defined the value 4 in a central place, all you have to do is change the line

`#define MAX_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL 4`

to the following:

`#define MAX_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL 3`

Afterwards, the value 4 will be changed to 3 automatically in both places in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// This header is only required in order to use the assert macro used below,
// but both this header and the assert macros are only used for debugging
// purposes and can be removed.
#include <assert.h>

// Instead of writing the value 720 in several places in the program, it is
// usually better to define the number in one place, so it can more easily be
// changed.
#define NUM_MINUTES 720

// Also, if the minimum and maximum random waiting times are defined in one
// central place, they are also easier to change, which actually must be done
// as part of the task.
#define MIN_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL 1
#define MAX_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL 4
#define MIN_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE 1
#define MAX_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE 4

// Since no more than one customer can arrive per minute, there can be no more
// than NUM_MINUTES customers, so this array is guaranteed to be large enough.
// If you want to save memory, you can use a linked list and dynamic memory
// allocation instead, but that may be slower.
static int customerArrivalTimes[NUM_MINUTES];

int main()
{
    // This will seed the random number generator.
    unsigned int seed = (unsigned)time( NULL );
    printf( "seeding with %u\n", seed );
    srand( seed );

    // This variable always holds the time the next customer will arrive.
    int nextArrival;

    // This variable holds the time the cashier will finish serving the current
    // customer. The value of -1 is reserved to indicate that no customer is
    // currently being serviced.
    int nextService = -1;

    // This variable keeps record of the maximum waiting time a single customer
    // experienced.
    int longestWait = 0;

    // This variable keeps track of the longest Queue Size ever encountered.
    int longestQueue = 0;

    // This variable specifies the current length of the queue.
    int queueLength = 0;

    // When queueLength == 0, queueStart specifies the index into the array
    // customerArrivalTimes which will hold the next customer that arrives, so
    // in that case it should be identical to the value of queueEnd.
    // When queueLength != 0, queueStart specifies the index into the array
    // customerArrivalTimes of the customer which is currently being serviced.
    int queueStart = 0;

    // When queueLength == 0, queueEnd specifies the index into the array
    // customerArrivalTimes which will hold the next customer that arrives, so
    // in that case it should be identical to the value of queueStart.
    // When queueLength != 0, queueEnd specifies the index into the array
    // customerArrivalTimes which will hold the next arriving customer (i.e.
    // one beyond the last customer in the queue).
    int queueEnd = 0;

    // This will use the random number generator to set the arrival time of
    // the first customer.
    nextArrival = rand() % (MAX_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL + 1 - MIN_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL) + MIN_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL;

    // This simulation will start at minute 0 and end at minute NUM_MINUTES - 1
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_MINUTES; i++ )
    {
        //check if the next customer is scheduled to arrive in this minute
        if ( nextArrival == i )
        {
            //update queueLength and test if record has been broken
            queueLength++;
            if ( queueLength > longestQueue ) longestQueue = queueLength;

            //print information message
            printf( "%03d:New customer arriving, queue length now: %d.\n", i, queueLength );

            //remember the arrival time of the current customer
            customerArrivalTimes[queueEnd++] = i;

            //set random arrival time for next customer
            nextArrival = rand() % (MAX_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL + 1 - MIN_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL) + MIN_MINUTES_PER_ARRIVAL + i;

            //if queue was empty, start servicing the new customer
            if ( queueLength == 1 )
            {
                // The following line will abort the program with an error
                // message if nextService is a valid time value (not -1).
                // This should not happen if the queue was empty. Therefore,
                // this would indicate a bug in the program.
                assert( nextService == -1 );

                //schedule completion time of next customer service
                nextService = rand() % (MAX_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE + 1 - MIN_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE) + MIN_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE + i;
            }
        }

        //check if customer service is scheduled to finish in this minute
        if ( nextService == i )
        {
            //print information message
            printf(
                "%03d:Customer service completed, total time: %d.\n",
                i, i - customerArrivalTimes[queueStart]
            );

            // This code block will update the variable longestWait if the
            // record was broken
            if ( longestWait < i - customerArrivalTimes[queueStart] )
            {
                longestWait = i - customerArrivalTimes[queueStart];
            }

            //update the starting point and length of the queue
            queueStart++;
            queueLength--;

            // The following line will abort the program with an error message
            // if queueLength ever becomes negative (which should never happen
            // and would indicate a bug in the program).
            assert( queueLength >= 0 );

            //if queue is not empty, start servicing the next customer
            if ( queueLength != 0 )
            {
                //schedule completion time of next customer service
                nextService = rand() % (MAX_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE + 1 - MIN_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE) + MIN_MINUTES_PER_SERVICE + i;
            }
            //otherwise indicate that no customer is currently being serviced
            else
            {
                nextService = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    // This will print the longest total waiting time a customer experienced.
    // This includes the waiting time for a customer to finish being serviced
    // by the cashier, although the task description does not clearly specify
    // whether this should be the case. Also, this does not take into account
    // whether customers still waiting in the queue when the store closes
    // will or already have had a longer waiting time, as the task does not
    // specify how these customers should be handled.
    printf( "Longest wait: %d\n", longestWait );

    // This will print the maximum queue length that was encountered.
    printf( "Longest queue: %d\n", longestQueue );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this code looks perfect with these notes and good spacing. Also helps a lot. I'll fix mine and send it. After that i will look your code word by word and will understand. Thanks a lot again i appreciate it.

Comment: @Fuat: I am pleased that you plan to fix your own solution, instead of simply passing in my solution. That way, you learn more. Also, the last person who did that got into a bit of trouble, because the teacher did not believe him that he wrote the solution himself. :)

Comment: @Fuat: Please note that meanwhile, I made a few minor changes to my program. I mainly fixed the comments a bit and added an `assert` statement.